# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a webscraper on a linux server. The full error is below

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
```

I have seen similar questions asked on stackoverflow, the solutions are to include the '--headless' and '--no-sandbox' arguments. However, I am already doing this.

I am able run this code locally, however, I am unable to make it work on the server.

I have also checked to see that everything is up to date, and everything is.

```
ChromeDriver 2.10.267518
selenium     3.141.0
```

Here is the code snippet where the error occurs.

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

I have also tried to run the above code without the executable_path option but I still get the same error.

Comment: It’s seems your chrome driver version is very old.By the way which version of chrome browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a config file that was setting the header value to True, so the code was trying to run with a browser and failing. This was a stupid mistake but I'm posting the solution anyway in case it helps someone.

I also had to remove the line below

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

and change this line

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

to

```
options.add_argument('headless')
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.10*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.10*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v33-36**

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=72.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.10* and the *Chrome Browser v72.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.